# SQL - Get all rows after a given column value occurs

Tags: sql

I'm working with flat files generated by VFPRO that have their row id's stored as a string. They look like this...

`_5261048AB`,
`_5261048WX`, 
`_526104FAZ`, `_526105DBB`,
`_526105OUH`

I'm writing a c# program that periodically checks these files, takes some values and moves them to an sql database. I can get the id value for the last row added to the database, but I want to then only select the rows that occur after that value to copy over.

So if the last row added to the database had a value of `_526104FAZ`, I would only want to get the rows after it `_526105DBB`,
`_526105OUH` from the flat file. Is this possible? Rows are created in the flat files in chronological order. Normally I could just do something trivial like

```
WHERE Create_Date > Last_Date
```

or

```
SELECT * WHERE Id > last Id
```

but with these Ids being random-ish strings and in a flat file I'm not sure how to approach.

I'm using `OleDbDataAdapter` in my c# to run the sql commands on the file if that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't simple string comparison work? `SELECT * table WHERE name > last_name`? These strings look comparable for this particular case.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Are you saying that the `id`'s are not always assigned in alphanumeric order?  That what you want to do is base your selection on the position of a row in the file?  *(As opposed to finding all rows where the `id` is greater than a specific value.)*  Your difficulty there is going to be that data in SQL is explicitly un-ordered.  Your file may have `'_526104FAZ'` as the 3rd row *(and so you want the 4th row on-wards)*, but once it's in SQL there is ***no*** concept of the "third row" or "fourth row".  Is that your problem?

Comment: @MatBailie Yes the id's aren't in order. It's basically an old networked till system and all the sales data is written to a .dbf file. A till that has been on site may write an id begining with  _52, but a newer till would write to the file with another value _12 for example. The rows are all added chronologically though so I just want the rows that are added after a given id value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm querying older .dbf files using oledbconnection. There's no dbms involved unfortunately. I tried to use ORDER BY and it didn't like that, but more basic sql commands like SELECT and WHERE seem to work.

Comment: @SeanT - Do the files have a `row_id` style column *(one that **is** sequentially allocated inside the file)*?  If so then you can use `WHERE row_id > COALESCE((SELECT row_id FROM source WHERE other_id = '_526104FAZ'), 0)`.  If there is no such column, you should do your filtering outside of SQL/oledbconnection.

Comment: @MatBailie Nope, I think I will have to pass each row in the file to sql server every time. Then insert where the id's don't exist. Either that or the reverse get all of the Id's from sql table then select rows from the file where those id's don't exist. It's going to be expensive though as flat files are sloooow, some of them have approx 100,000 rows

Comment: You just changed the problem statement.  Is your ***real*** requirement to import only rows with an id you haven't already seen?

Comment: @MatBailie that's basically crappy a fall back option, There's a huge volume of rows, 20 sites each with 10-20 tills, 10-100,000 rows on each till. this c# program will sit on the tills and forward the data to an api. I wanted to query the tills every 5mins or so and forward 10's of rows. Not have to send all the rows back and forth each time.

Comment: @SeanT - I didn't propose a solution, I asked if that is your actual problem statement.  You've conflated ***how*** you go about ***solving*** the problem with how to ***describe*** it.  For example, you ***could*** solve this by each till being told "send me all records that occur after 'xyz'...", or you could have the till ask the receiver "what's the latest record you've seen?", either way the till can then do the filtering locally.  Stop inferring solutions for now, concentrate on accurately describing the requirement and the context.

Comment: @MatBailie The requirement is the initial statement, get all rows from a given .dbf flat file that occur after the first occurrence of a specified column value in a row. Assume the column is not ordered and is varchar so values can be anything.

Comment: @MatBailie Obviously if this is not possible then I will have to go back to the drawing board and come up with another approach

Answer (score 0):

I recommend picking up all the files generated at the time your process runs and then load them to a staging table in SQL.

Once done loading into stage , Insert data into original(production) table  by either left joining the original table and the stage on id where id in original table is null.

Comment: The point is that the `id` being used isn't sequentially allocated.  The OP can't use `MAX()` or `>=`, the OP needs to base the filtering on the position within the file *(later rows may have an `id` less than the value being searched against)*.  Which doesn't fit with your current answer.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie , In my response above I mentioned two responses and one of them was to do a left join against Original table with Stage where Id is null in original table . This will ensure no duplicates are loaded and also only rows that do not exist in the original table are loaded too.